# Error detected in pubspec.yaml: Error on line 49, column 13: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier? ╷ 49 │ fonts: │ ^

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

```
name: form
# Read more about Android https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    -family: Rubik
       fonts:
      - assest: fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf
      - assest: fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf
   - family: DancingScript
      fonts:
      - assest: fonts/DINOT-Regular.ttf
      - assest: fonts/DINOT-Bold.otf
       weight: 700
   - family: Cookie
      fonts:
      - assest : fronts/Cookie-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: I'm guessing you have something messed up in your indentation.  YAML is indentation-sensitive.  Docs on YAML are at https://yaml.org.

Answer (score 1):

Reason for above error is everything in pubspec.yaml file has to be align properly so update your pubspec.yaml file with above code.

https://prnt.sc/wanxfg click here to solve your error